# Bootstrap - Responsive Logo, Menu and Navbar

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am a noob and this is my first real experience with Bootstrap. I have been trying to position my logo in the navbar towards the left and aligned with the drop down links inside the navbar toggle class . I have attached screenshots of what I am ultimately trying to do/copy, as it is easier to show than for me to try and describe it.

When viewed on mobile device, the menu turns into a dropdown and is moved under a larger logo.

The site I would like to use as reference is http://www.fidelityhome.net

I have been playing around with the size by giving a max width and max height, as well as auto, I have tried moving the logo out of the navbar header and even out of the container.

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="large-4 columns centered-text-responsive"> <div class="logo-container"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo3.png" alt="logo"
                    style="max-width:600px; max-height:200px; width:100%;" /></a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your html structure should be like this,

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                          data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                         class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" class="logo"><img src="assets/logo.png" alt=""></a>
              </div>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                  <li class=""><a href="#">1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
              </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try on you logo

```
<img src="logo.png" class="image-responsive">
```

Is a class of bootstrap, that directly make your image responsive, i hope this help you.

Comment: Do you have an screenshot of what is happening

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
<a class="large-4 columns centered-text-responsive"> <div class="logo-container"><a href="index.html"><img src="http://www.fidelityhome.net/wp-content/uploads/Fidelity-Home-Energy-Logo.png" alt="logo" style="max-width:600px; max-height:200px; width:100%;" /></a>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">   
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Test it here: http://www.bootply.com/Yl1U4fPfb9

Comment: That is definitely on track with what I am looking for. Thank you so much! I hit the up arrow for your post, but since I am new it popped up saying I have to wait until a rep of 15 before it will be publicly changed.

Comment: I tried using this and I get a giant white border around dropdown. Is there a way to make it so the menus are on the right until it gets to a certain size and then it goes underneath the logo?

'

http://www.bootply.com/RS9l6YVtw1